# C# Regex how can I shortcut all those matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
    var match = Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)ab.*?");
    var match2 = Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)bc.*?");
    var match3 = Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)de.*?");
    var match4 = Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)ef.*?");
    var match5= Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)gh.*?");
    var match6= Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)ij.*?");
    var match7 = Regex.Match(GetActiveWindowTitle(), "(?i)kl.*?");

 if (match4.Success || match.Success || match2.Success || match3.Success etc....)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sucess");
            }
```

How can I make something shorter, is there any Regex class functions to regroup many matches ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"(?i)(?:ab|bc|de|ef|gh|ij|kl).*?"
```

Use the pipe `|` token for alternation.

Note that the `?:` indicates that these are "non-capturing parentheses." It is optional, but is usually done for performance to indicate that you don't need to capture what is inside the parentheses (the default behavior). In this case we are only using the parentheses to enclose the alternation options.